# How to get Table of Contents from SCORM 1.2

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

im trying to make a review system for SCORM (php based web app)
So, at first You upload Your SCORM and web app make table of contets. Listing all slider and their titles.

How i can read all slides titles from SCORM package ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the imsmanifest.xml within the Content Aggregation Model (CAM) package (zip).  The `<organizations>` node will have the breakdown with identifier ref attributes to resources they align with.

Hope that helps.